# Using a google drive script to send a confirmationmail containing a photo upon form submittal

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a form for a mailing list. That form also has a pretty common script that sends a confirmation email to the user upon form submittal

My code so far:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[2];
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 
                    "Insider emails", 
                    "Thanks for registering for our mailing list.",                    
                    {name:"Blah"});
}​
```

What code would I use to insert an image of a coupon in the body of the email?

Answer (score 3):

Example from the documentation

```
function inlineImage() {
  var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png").getBlob().setName("googleLogoBlob");
  var youtTubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/logos/youtube_logo_standard_againstwhite-vflKoO81_.png").getBlob().setName("youtTubeLogoBlob");

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    "sg.appsscript@gmail.com",
    "Logos",
    "", 
    { htmlBody: 
         "inline Google Logo<img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br/> inline YouTube Logo <img src='cid:youTubeLogo'>",
     inlineImages: 
         { googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
           youTubeLogo:youtTubeLogoBlob
          }
    }

    );
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#sendEmail